# A Before action callback method redirects multiple times while forcing the user to change password in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

A scenario needs, when User logs in, if didn't change the password, he should redirect_to the change password path I tried in following ways

```
1)
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :check_password, if: :current_user
     def check_password 
      if current_user.present? && 
         current_user.try(:created_at).try(:to_datetime) == 
         current_user.try(:password_changed_at).try(:to_datetime)
        redirect_to change_password_admin_user_path(current_user)
      end
     end
    end
2)    
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :check_password, only: [:change_password, :update_password]
     
  def change_password
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
    
  def update_password
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   if @user.valid_password?(params[:old_password])
     if @user.update_attributes(password: params[:new_password], password_confirmation: params[:reenter_password])
      flash[:notice] = 'Password changed successfully, please login with new password'
      redirect_to new_user_session_path and return
    else
      flash[:alert] = @user.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
    end
  else
   flash[:alert] = "Old password you've entered is invalid"
  end
  redirect_to change_password_admin_user_path(@user.id)
 end
end
 
3)   
class Admin::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
 skip_before_action :check_password, only: :destroy
end
```

I am forcing the user to change the password but it throws redirecting multiple times error

Comment: you mean `DoubleRenderError` ? where the error point to (class/line of code) ?

Comment: That's not an error. That's expected behaviour as far as I understand from your issue. Rails runs the before_action, sees that it needs to redirect, redirects the user and tells you in the logs that it did the redirection. I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".):

Comment: why do you have `password_changed_at` method? Devise doesn't have that

Comment: I have devise security gem to implement password expiring @blackbiron

Comment: @gangothri if you're using `devise security` gem then you can use this method: https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security/blob/master/lib/devise-security/models/password_expirable.rb#L40, to clear `password_changed_at` immediately after the user sign-up, so that the `devise hook` https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security/blob/master/lib/devise-security/hooks/password_expirable.rb#L6 will do the rest, you no need to handle this logic yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according your comment, you're using [devise-security gem](https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security), so you can use the method [need_change_password!](https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security/blob/master/lib/devise-security/models/password_expirable.rb#L40) (which will clear `password_changed_at`) right after the user sign-up, so that the devise hook [password_expirable](https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security/blob/master/lib/devise-security/hooks/password_expirable.rb#L6) will check and force new user change pass, you no need to handle this logic by yourself.

Comment: current_user.need_password_changed! inside check_password action Solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
1)
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :check_password, if: :current_user # this is why you're getting multiple redirect.
     def check_password 
      if current_user.present? && 
         current_user.try(:created_at).try(:to_datetime) == 
         current_user.try(:password_changed_at).try(:to_datetime)
        redirect_to change_password_admin_user_path(current_user)
      end
     end
    end
```

So, don't use like this.

How about move the check_password method to another controller?

Ex.

```rb
class DashboardController < ActionController::Base
  def dashboard
    if current_user.present? && 
      current_user.try(:created_at).try(:to_datetime) == 
      current_user.try(:password_changed_at).try(:to_datetime)
      redirect_to change_password_admin_user_path(current_user)
    end
  end
end
```

Plus, don't show any menu unless he had changed password.

Comment: @gangothri
did delete the 'before_action :check_password, if: :current_user' line from ApplicationController?